# What does "bent of mind" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I read this in my horoscope. I couldn't find any definition for 'bent of mind'. Please help.

"Devout, devoted to parents and having a religious bent of mind, you believe in the dictum that service to humanity is service to God."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - so the definition for the above extract is “a religious natural ability”?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - you should do that, and give proper definitions to what is asked. See my answer below if you get confused.

Comment: @user66974 - On this site, answers to low quality questions are deplored, and attract downvotes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - probably the OP (a new user) is not as highly educated as you are. Probably the answer is not that intuitive to users, especially to non natives, given that you gave a wrong definition yourself.

Comment: @user66974 - That's why there is [English Language **Learners** Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - that’s not what you CVoted the question for.

Comment: @user66974 - feel free to sue me.

Comment: You've heard of left-leaning or right-leaning websites. Very similar to a lean, or tendency, the word bent is movement to the side, away from a neutral position. Bent is tendency.

Comment: From _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003): "**bent** _n_ {irreg. fr. _bend_} **1 a :** a strong inclination or interest : BIAS **b :** a special inclination or capacity : TALENT **2 :** capacity of endurance **3 :** a transverse framework (s in a bridge ) to carry lateral as well as vertical loads **syn[onyms]** see GIFT [which notes that "BENT is nearly equal to APTITUDE, but it stresses inclination perhaps more than specific ability {a family with an artistic _bent_}"]." Definition 1(a) is the one most relevant to the phrase "bent of mind."

Answer (score -2):

I know I am late in part but *bent of mind* in a sentence can mean to think very hard about or put a lot of effort into one particular thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).